# Requisição http caindo no catchError

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou tentando fazer requisição http dentro do httpInterceptor, porém sempre cai no catcherror, é impresso no console o "caiu no err".

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('token', authToken);
    headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'bearer '+authToken);

    if(authToken != null){
        if(req.url !== AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'plano/busca'){
        let http: HttpClient = this.injector.get(HttpClient);

        return http.get('api....', {headers: headers}).pipe(switchMap((response) => {
            console.log('caiu no res')
            console.log(response);
            const newRequest = req.clone({
                setHeaders: { Authorization: `bearer ${authToken}`, token: `${authToken}` }
            });
            return next.handle(newRequest);
        }),
        (err) => {
            console.log('caiu no err');
            if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            console.log(err)
            return Observable.throw(err); 
        }}
    )}else {
        return next.handle(req);
        }
    }
}
```

@Edit:

Tentei fazer a requisição dentro do serviço, agora eu consigo o retorno do request, porém não está clonando a requisição e adicionando o header:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('token', authToken);
    headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'bearer '+authToken);

    if(authToken != null){
        if(req.url !== AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'plano/busca'){
        let http: HttpClient = this.injector.get(HttpClient);

        this.authService.validaPlano().subscribe((res) =>{
            console.log(res);
            if(res.data.vencido == true){
                this.authService.Logout();
            }else{
            const newRequest = req.clone({
                setHeaders: { Authorization: `bearer ${authToken}`, token: `${authToken}` }
            });
            return next.handle(newRequest);
            }
        },
        (err) => {
            if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            return Observable.throw(err); 
        }
    })
    }else {
        return next.handle(req);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Já verifiquei e os headers estão funcionando corretamente, testei no postman e a requisição retorna um response json... Porque pode estar caindo no err?

Comment: O status da requisição é 20X? Tipo 200 ou 204?

Comment: É do tipo 200 Eduardo

Comment: Dei uma editada com outra tentativa, essa chegou mais próxima